# Rounding elements for IE

Tags: php, css, rounded-corners

on my wordpress site http://www.101river.com the edges of elements are rounded but only in firefox, safari and Chrome because Ie does not support css3 the elements are not rounded in IE. I know there are many tricks to make this make corners rounded in IE just don't know the easiest. Can some one please give some example code to make this work?

PHP

Comment: +1 for IE making things difficult...

Comment: There's always the 'degrade gracefully' approach, although this is of course a big design decision as you're using curved corners so much.

Comment: Many people are suggesting the CSS3PIE approach, which will do what you want it to, though I feel the responsiveness isn't exactly great. This solution works by adding VML (Vector Markup Language) dynamically into your markup, which IE recognizes and allows for things like rounded corners. I believe performance / experience should be valued over design, so I would say, as Alex has said, allow your designs to degrade gracefully in IE, so that they get square corners. http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Answer (score 5):

CSS3 is pretty tricky to get right across all browsers. I use http://css3pie.com/ to get it working in IE as well. Not everything works, but rounded corners will for sure.

Pretty good walk through on there to set it up too.

Edit: It works all the way back to IE6 as well!

Answer (score 4):

I'd check out [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com), as well as his [breakdown of the other projects in this space](http://css3pie.com/documentation/product-comparison/).

Answer (score 0):

I've always been fond of [Spiffy Corners](http://www.spiffycorners.com/) myself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download [DD roundies](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/) JavaScript functions for creating rounded corners.
2. Then put this in your HTML:

`<head>`
  `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />`
  `<title>My Site</title>`
  `<link id="stylesheet1" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />`
  `<!--[if IE]>`
    `<script src="scripts/DD_roundies.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
    `<script>`
      `DD_roundies.addRule('.rounded', '5px');`
    `</script>`
  `<![endif]-->`
`</head>`

Some other techniques including the classic CSS rounded corners using images:

- [25 Rounded Corners Techniques with CSS](http://www.devwebpro.com/25-rounded-corners-techniques-with-css/)